# inline::cxxfunction not displaying well in knitr

Tags: r, inline, knitr, rcpp

I'm having problems getting C++ code (written via the cxxfunction in the inline package) to display nicely when using knitr.  Here's a MWE:

```
<html>
<body>

<!--begin.rcode
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)
test <- cxxfunction(signature(xR="numeric"), body="
  double x = as<double>(xR);
  return(wrap(x));
  ", plugin="RcppArmadillo")
end.rcode-->

</body>
</html>
```

When I knit this code, it reformats the body argument by replacing all new lines with "\n" and it makes it very hard to read.  Are there any work-arounds to this?

Comment: Are you running the last version of knitr ? Because I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ah, yes, updating from 1.5 to 1.6 fixes the problem (I updated Rcpp, inline, and RcppArmadillo but forgot about knitr)!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: As indicated by [FAQ 1](http://bit.ly/knitr-faq), do `update.packages()` to see if problems just go away magically :)

Comment: Sorry, I'll be sure to do that in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a major change as listed in the [release notes of **knitr** 1.6](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/tag/v1.6): the default chunk option `tidy = TRUE` was changed to `FALSE`. That is why your line breaks are no longer turned to literal `\n`'s with **knitr** 1.6.

Answer (score 3):

Well now you have **two** reasons to switch to Rcpp Attributes: First, it is easier to use. Second, it renders better in knitr :)

The following code should do the same -- and not how Attributes handles all the conversion for you:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)
cppfunction('double mytest(double x) {
  return x;
}', depends="RcppArmadillo")
```

Try rendering that in knitr.

Comment: Hmm...  When I knit that code, I get the following line:
cppFunction("double mytest(double x) {\n  return x;\n}", depends = "RcppArmadillo").
cppFunction is definitely nicer to use, though!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Rcpp engine in knitr:

````
```{r, engine = "Rcpp"}
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total / n;
}
```
````

The chunk will be syntax highlighted as C++, and the function will be made available to other chunks with `cppFunction()`. The only downside is that compilation is not cached.